# jQuery - my function gets reference of wrong DOM object

Tags: jquery, dom, reference

I've created my own hover function that changes opacity of text. It looks like this:

```
jQuery.fn.menuHover = function ()
{
            var object = this;
            $(object).css({'opacity':'0.2'});
            $(document).delegate(object, 'mouseenter', function() {
                $(object)
                    .stop()
                    .animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
            });
            $(document).delegate(object, 'mouseleave', function() {
                $(object)
                    .stop()
                    .animate({opacity: 0.2}, 'slow');
            });
   };
```

And then I call this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.menu_text').menuHover();    
    });
</script>
```

It works fine, but it works with entire document instead only with '.menu_text' class . I mean that variable 'this' == document instead of '.menu_text'. Question is how to change it to operate only with selected object?

Comment: By this I mean that I dont want use default jQuery hover, because my function gets better effect. I want just to improve my code, sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

*It should be noted that `.delegate()` has been superseded by `.on()` for a few versions now.*

That isn't the recommended way to add new methods to jQuery objects (`$()`). The recommended way is

```
$.fn.extend({
  menuHover: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

But that's more a nitpick.

The problem, I suspect, was passing `.delegate()` a jQuery object as its first parameter.  [The documentation of `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) specifies that the first parameter shall be (signature 1) a string, (signature 2) a string, or (signature 3) a string - what likely happened was jQuery threw up its hands at the non-string and just applied the handler to `$(document)`. This matches what happens when I use `$(document).on()` without a selector. The other possible explanation (revealed during testing) is that using `object` (a.k.a. everything the selector matched) in the handler *will* fade everything at once.

The following should work (tested in jsFiddle):

```
$.fn.extend({
  menuHover: function() {
    this
      .css({opacity: '0.2'})
      .on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
      })
      .on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.2}, 'slow');
      });
  }
});
```

Explanations:

1. Functions extending jQuery objects already have the object in question as `this`. The `.on()` method executes the handler with `this` set to a raw DOM node, so we have to call `$` on it before using jQuery methods.
2. I have removed the delegation approach, and just made the method apply to everything it is passed. This shouldn't be a problem.
3. `var object` is completely unnecessary with the ability to use `this` inside `.on()` (and, indeed, using `object` was producing **The Wrong Result**); I've just called methods on `this`.